# tkcalendar: dateEntry being blocked from view unless clicked multiple times

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

Firstly, I will apologise for the bad explanation because I do not really understand the issue.

However, in any of my programs when I use a dateEntry, it will at first be covered, and requires multiple clicks to get rid of this cover and to show the dates.

Please see video for better explanation: [here](https://youtu.be/Orv9NpQosgM)
Also, a picture at the bottom (i think) to showcase this.

Example code:

```
import tkinter
import tkcalendar

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Example")
window.geometry("1200x750")
window.configure(bg = "white")

dateentry_example = tkcalendar.DateEntry(window, locale = "en_US", date_pattern = "y/mm/dd")
dateentry_example.grid(sticky = "N", padx = 500, pady = 50)

window.mainloop()
```

I do apologise if this is an easy fix that I somehow missed in the documentation.

I mainly expected that when clicking the drop down arrow that it would display all the dates automatically, however it requires promting multiple times to allow that to happen.

Comment: This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/41) for MacOS. You could try [this workaround](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar/issues/41#issuecomment-626991627) although several comments say it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much, a shame that that is an issue, but overall not too bad :) But yeah the old fixes don't work anymore